# Add one day into Joda-Time DateTime

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I have date `Wed May 08 00:00:00 GMT+06:30 2013`. I add one day into it by using [Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) [DateTime](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) like this.

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(date);
dateTime.plusDays(1);
```

When I print dateTime, I got this date `2013-05-08T00:00:00.000+06:30`. The joda date time didn't add one day. I haven't found any error.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know joda, but I assume `plusDays()` returns a new `DateTime` object. Try `datetime = dateTime.plusDays(1)`. Confirmed from the [docs](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#plusDays%28int%29).

Comment: @Phylogenesis you might want to post that as an answer, because it is correct.

Comment: @Barend it's been posted as an answer now. No need to clutter the question.

Comment: I was apparently in the process of posting the answer when the comment thread happened.  Had I seen it happening, I would have agreed Phylogenesis should post as an answer.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

The `plusDays` method is not a mutator.  It returns a copy of the given `DateTime` object with the change made rather than changing the given object.

If you want to actually change the variable `dateTime` value, you'll need:

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(date);
dateTime = dateTime.plusDays(1);
```

Comment: maybe add the words 'Immutable' and 'Mutable' to best explain this to such a question

Answer (score 32):

If you want add days to current date time instance, use [MutableDateTime](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/MutableDateTime.html)

```
MutableDateTime dateTime = new MutableDateTime(date);  
dateTime.addDays(1);
```